# how to combine result of select statement to the other table with different database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, sql

I'm having a hard time to combine the result my select statement to the other table with different database.

This is one of my select statement and it works fine:

Database name "**LIS**" table "**Legal_Records**"

```
Select CaseNo,Judicial_level,Received_date,Due_Date, (SELECT Max(cast(Due_date as datetime)) FROM Legal_Records subc WHERE subc.CaseNo=c.CaseNo Group by c.CaseNo) AS MaxDue_Date from Legal_Records c
```

Result :

[image]

Here is the other Query and it also works fine:

Database name : "**Pandimandata2002**" Table name : "**tblCrew**"

```
Select CaseNo, Lastname,Vessel,Status from tblCrew where Pandimandata2002.dbo.tblCrew.CaseNo like '%CRW%' and (Status not like '%clos%' and Status not like '%settl%' and Status not like '%ca%cel%') and Status like '%court%' and ClubCode like '%TR%'
```

Result:

[image]

What i want to do is Add the column name "Judicial_level" from database "LIS" table "Legal_Records" to table "tblCrew" database "Pandimandata2002" when the CaseNo match to the other table.

I hope I made myself clear! thank you..

Answer (score 0):

```
Select lr.Judicial_level, tc.* 
FROM LIS.dbo.Legal_Records lr
INNER JOIN Pandimandata2002.dbo.tblCrew tc 
ON lr.CaseNo = tc.CaseNo
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but can u make it more specific base on my sample query because it is on different database. TIA!

Comment: have you tried running the query first? the query itself should retrieve all the records. from there, you can continue to add in the filters.

Comment: As u can see I have two select statement on the first query to get the latest judical level base on the latest due date. So it will not get the result i wanted.

Comment: yes i understand what you want me to do for you. however, i have already provided you the basic code on how to retrieve data from two databases. without filters (or maybe in your understanding, without the WHERE clauses and stuff), it should work by retrieving all the data. PLEASE try the above code first and if it DOES NOT RETRIEVE DATA FROM TWO DATABASES (do not bother about the latest due date blahblahs first), then let me know so I can help you further.